# LinkedList implementation in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I was starting to learn data structures and I successfully implemented LinkedList in Java and Python with ease. But something is not right with my C code and I am not getting the output. This pointer concept is really bugging me and I would appreciate it if someone could tell me my mistake in this implementation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

void append(int data, struct node *head, struct node *tail){
  struct node *newNode = ((struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)));   
  (*newNode).data = data;
  (*newNode).next = NULL;
  if (head == NULL)
  {
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
  }else{
    tail -> next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
  }

}

void traverse(struct node *head){
  struct node *temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL){
    printf("%d",(*temp).data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}


int main()
{
  printf("Hey linked list \n");
  struct node *head = NULL;
  struct node *tail = NULL;
  /* code */
  append(3,head,tail);
  append(4,head,tail);
  append(5,head,tail);
  traverse(head);
  return 0;
}
```

BTW , like head always points to the first node in the linked list , I have a pointer tail which always points to the last node in the linked list. This way appending data to the list is easy and is constant time.

Thank you guys and I would appreciate an easy to understand answer..

Comment: So many questions available, search!

Comment: Aside - syntax tip, change `(*newNode).data = data;` etc. to `newNode->data = data;`

Comment: Dont retype return value of `malloc`

Comment: `struct list { struct node *head, *tail } aList = {NULL, NULL};append(3, &aList);` instead of `struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *tail = NULL; append(3,head,tail);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah thats what I had in the beginning. Just tried this to see if maybe that works

Comment: There must be a dup for this.  Likely, thousands:(

Comment: You really shouldn't post a lot of code and then ask people to "find the mistake somewhere in the implementation". Indicators like "something is not right with my C code" and "I'm not getting the output" don't narrow it down. Have you used the debugger or other debugging techniques and narrowed it down?

Comment: [Combine head and tail in a structure](http://ideone.com/nEClB6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `head` and `tail` pointers aren't getting set as you expect.  Everything in `c` is pass by value, so essentially all arguments passed to functions are local variables that have scope only within that function.  When you pass `head` and `tail` to `append`, local copies of each are made. You make assignments to `head` and `tail`, but these assignments are lost once the function exits and the variables go out of scope.  You must pass the address of these pointers to `append` and dereference them there if you want the assignments to "stick" outside of the function.

```
void append(int data, struct node **head, struct node **tail)
{
  struct node *newNode = ((struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)));   
  (*newNode).data = data;
  (*newNode).next = NULL;
  if (head == NULL)
  {
    *head = newNode;  // dereference head here so this assignment will persist outside of this function
    *tail = newNode;
  }else{
    (*tail) -> next = newNode;
    *tail = newNode;
  }
}

.....

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hey linked list \n");
  struct node *head = NULL;
  struct node *tail = NULL;
  /* code */
  append(3,&head,&tail);
  append(4,&head,&tail);
  append(5,&head,&tail);
  traverse(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code only passes *copies* of `head` and `tail` pointers so the caller's values do not get updated. You need double star arguments in `append`, and to pass their *address* so they can be updated, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void append(int data, struct node **head, struct node **tail){
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
        *tail = newNode;
    }else{
        (*tail)->next = newNode;
        *tail = newNode;
    }
}

void traverse(struct node *head){
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d",(*temp).data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hey linked list \n");
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    append(3, &head, &tail);
    append(4, &head, &tail);
    append(5, &head, &tail);
    traverse(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Hey linked list
345
```

Comment: thank you man. that helps. coming from java and python , pointers in C is tough to understand